# Rounding Down sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Any idea where the beelow would be rounding down the total salary for employee 11 is 10.44 but its rounding it down as 10 for some resaon even though their both set to decimals (8,2)

```
   ALTER procedure [dbo].[hms_GetEmployeeSallaryByEmpNo]
    (

    @Id int
   )
as
/* lets make our tempory tables */
create table #contracts
( 
empno INT,
contract_id INT
)

 DECLARE @contract_id int
 DECLARE @totalsallary decimal(8,2)
 begin 
  INSERT into #contracts SELECT c.emp_no,c.contract_id
  FROM  contract c
  where c.emp_no =  @Id AND c.leave_date='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
 end 

 SET @totalsallary =(select SUM(salary)
from #contracts c,salary s
where s.contract_id = c.contract_id)
return @totalsallary
```

Answer (score 1):

Stored Procedures can only return *integer* values:

From [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx):

> Stored procedures can return an integer value to a calling procedure or an application.

What you want is an *output* parameter:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[hms_GetEmployeeSalaryByEmpNo]
(
   @Id int,
   @totalsalary decimal(8,2) OUTPUT
)
...
SET @totalsalary =
(
    SELECT SUM(salary)
    FROM #contracts c,salary s
    WHERE s.contract_id = c.contract_id
)

--return @totalsalary  -- not necessary anymore
```

or a Scalar Value Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[hms_GetEmployeeSalaryByEmpNo]
(
    @Id int
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(8,2)
AS
....
SET @totalsalary =
(
    SELECT SUM(salary)
    FROM #contracts c,salary s
    WHERE s.contract_id = c.contract_id
)

RETURN @totalsalary
```

*also note that I corrected the spelling of "salary" in my examples.

Comment: You've acquired an extra `@` on your output parameter, but I've +1ed anyway.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That is a valid (though unconventional) identifier.

Comment: @MartinSmith - true, but they'd need to do it in both the parameter list and the `SET` statement. At the moment, it's inconsistent. Also, [not recommended](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874(v=sql.105).aspx): "Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with double at signs (@@). To avoid confusion with these functions, you should not use names that start with @@."

Comment: @DStanley but that means i could no longer do my temprory table check yes ? i need that in employer was strict about that

Comment: No you can do pretty much whatever you want in either case.  Be aware that both will execute _for each employee_ so if you are going to call this function for many employees in one query you might look at returning a table instead.

Comment: @DStanley

where do i put the return as statment in relation to my original query thenr / its not as its going by employee number so only ever one employee but many sallarys

Comment: @davidb I'm not sure exactly what you're asking - do some research on Table Valued Functions.

Comment: i asking i need to keep the proecuedure the same but sort this decimal is their no way of you re editing the code to show me how plz